# How to prevent user from accessing route directly in express?

Tags: node.js, express, web-applications

I am developing a webapp where users fill in their contact details in a form and submit the form. After submission, I either redirect them to `/failure` or `/success` where

```
app.get("/success", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/success.html");
});

app.get("/failure", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/failure.html");
});
```

However, the user is also able to access `/failure` and `/success` if they simply type these in in the path of the url. How can I prevent this? I only want the failure/success pages to be visible after form submission.

Comment: set something in header or your post body (as hidden param) and read it in both of your routes i.e. `/success` & `/failure`

Answer (score 0):

Use a conditional statement like if the messaged entered by the user is inserted the redirect to the route success or else return to failure.
Example.
If the data was successfully inserted
redirect('/success')
else
redirect('/failure')

Answer (score 0):

set something in header or your post body (as hidden param in form) and read it in both of your routes i.e. `/success` & `/failure`

Example

Form

```html
<form action="<action>" method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <!-- this is your validation field -->
    <!-- (redirect this value onto your success or failure routes as a query param) -->
    <input type="hidden" name="validation" value="true" />

    ...
    <!-- continue with your form -->
</form>
```

Then in your routes:

```javascript
app.get("/success", function(req, res) {
    if (req.query.validation == true)
        res.sendFile(__dirname + "/success.html");
    else
        res.json({ error: 403, message: "Forbidden" });
});

// same goes for /failure
```